# How to alter the schema of a database to introduce new features or change the current features

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework

I'm developing an app using Zend Framwork using Git for version control.

What is the best approach for updating the schema and the database when one of us makes an update to the db structure?

currently, we have to blow out the tables and recreate them manually to reflect the new updates.

Answer (score 1):

A noteworthy implementation of a schema manager for ZF apps is [Akrabat Db Schema Manager](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/akrabat_db_schema_manager-zend-framework-database-migrations/) by [Rob Allen](http://twitter.com/akrabat). It uses migration scripts as suggested by @ceteras above. The link above includes code to use it with `Zend_Tool` though the library could be used on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I always keep track of all changes on two fronts:

1. I keep an empty version of the database and update the structure every time
2. I take care to write small scripts for every little change done. These are mostly DDL scripts (alter table add column etc), and are always kept in a well defined structure, with comments linking the statements to the tasks from Bugzilla/Jira whatever is used.
   Most of the time I make sure that these scripts are safe to be executed several times without errors.

Even if for some tasks I'm not the only one making changes, it's not difficult to synchronise our work, using svn.

Everything must be tested on at least one copy of the production environment.

Another way would be to use some database diff tools, these would compare the live database to your development database and generate scripts for changes to be done. I think Navicat has this feature. Some see this as a lot safer, well I think this is more chaotic. If you want a well done job, you do it yourself.

Comment: So do I. I use ubuntu and centos, mysql, apache/php, my colleagues do a lot of work in java, also. We use Jira for organizing our tasks (used to use bugzilla), and we keep all our code in subversion. I don't see how using LAMP prevents someone from dealing with database changes the way I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [DBDeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/)

> dbdeploy is a Database Change
>   Management tool. It’s for developers
>   or DBAs who want to evolve their
>   database design – or refactor their
>   database – in a simple, controlled,
>   flexible and frequent manner.

Theres also a [good tutorial here](http://www.davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy/) on using DBDeploy alongside [Phing](http://phing.info/trac/) (*a PHP project build system or build tool based on Apache Ant*)

Comment: Very interesting, unfortunatelly their php implementation page seems broken ( http://dbdeploy.com/software/php/ ), there's nothing in there.

Also interesting on their home page, "Drawing from our experiences, we’ve found that one of the easiest ways to allow people to change the database is by using version-controlled SQL delta scripts." - that's how I actually do it without the tool.

Comment: thank you seengee, this looks interesting...i think this is the kind of thing i was looking for:

http://www.davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy/

Answer (score 0):

Recently majority of frameworks provide a feature called `migrations.` Migrations are a convenient way for you to alter your database in a structured and organized manner. You could edit fragments of SQL by hand but you would then be responsible for telling other developers that they need to go and run them. You’d also have to keep track of which changes need to be run against the production machines next time you deploy.

In ZendFramework however, there is same concept but with the name Db_Schema_Manager. You can use that to keep track of changes in the database done by any developer, all you have to do is to run the ZendTools all over again.

Here is the link of how Db_Schema_Manager can be used:
http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Db_Schema_Manager+-+Rob+Allen